# See if number is in Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

So I have a form that registers users,

```
             <form class="" ng-submit="vm.passwordRegister()">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Register
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.number" class="form-control" placeholder="Client Number" ng-Blur="vm.numberCheck()"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail Address" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" ng-model="vm.password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" ng-model="vm.secret" class="form-control" placeholder="Account Secret" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-if="AccountOpen.$value">Register <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-if="!AccountOpen.$value" disabled>Register Disabled</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

The user enters a customer number at the beginning of the form and a secret at the end of the form.

In the end I will want to be sure of two things before creating the user.

```
1. The customer number exists in Firebase
2. The secret matches the customer number entered
```

Right now all I'm trying to do is call a function `vm.numberCheck()` that checks if the customer number or `number` exists and if so returns a snapshot or `snap` to the user. I will then mark that field as valid on the html side and allow for form submission.

My function looks like the following:

```
    vm.numberCheck = function ($scope, $vm, $window) {

        ref.child('clientNumbers').startAt(vm.number).endAt(vm.number).once('value', function(snap) {
            console.log('accounts matching customer number', snap.val());
        });

    }
```

The only way for me to get data returned is to simply click in the number field and blur without typing anything (provide an empty query) If I type anything in the field even if it is copied and pasted from firebase it returns null.

What am I doing wrong?

I created a JSFIDDLE and added everything I could think of but it still won't run. But here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/05dds4v3/5/ connected to a test firebase application I created.

Comment: there should not be parameter in your `vm.numberCheck ` function..it should be `vm.numberCheck = function ()`

Comment: That changed nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a working jsbin that shows how to detect the existence of a number in a list: http://jsbin.com/pesimo/1/edit?js,output

The crucial function is:

```
function checkIfNumberExists(number) {
  log('Checking if '+number+' exists, this may take a moment');
  ref.child('clientNumbers').child(number).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    log('Got a value, let\'s see if the number exists');
    if (snapshot.val() === null) {
      log('Our number does not yet exist, let\'s create it');
      ref.child('clientNumbers').child(number).set(true, function(error) {
        if (error) {
          log('Error creating number: '+error.toString());
        } 
        else {
          log('Number created, check if it exists now\n');
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      log('Yes, our number exists\n');
    }
  });
}
```

Note that I did not create AngularJS nor AngularFire nor jQuery, so that the solution focuses purely on detecting if a specific child node exists. This is often key in isolating a problem (and also one of the steps in providing an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). By reducing the problem to its core, you will either find the cause of your problem or make it as easy as possible for people to help you (since they need to debug fewer technologies).